# 100% height of content - px

Tags: html, css, height

I have a page with height 100%:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="header" class="clearfix">

    </header>
    <div class="main-container clearfix">
        <aside id="sideLeft">

        </aside><!-- #sideLeft -->
        <div id="content">
            <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- #main-container -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
height: 45px;
}
.main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
margin-left: 20%;
}

#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sideLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

But I want to make content 100% - height of header (in px), to don't show scrolling on the page.

I try to add `position: absolute;` to `#header` and `.main-container` but it's not helping (scroll still showing).

Live example: http://indoor.powerhtml.ru/30/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS cannot perform calculations and manipulation on page, it is just a stylesheet. You have to use JS for this.

jQuery snippet to do what you want is

```
$("#header").height($("#header").height()); //This automatically converts % to px
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/rZRaQ/)

Comment: Yeah, it can. With CSS(3) you can specify something to be 25%+10 pixels. Or in this case, 100% - someNumber of pixels. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional-notation

Comment: @enhzflep, You misunderstood the answer, I am saying `calculations and manipulation on pages`.